# How can I prevent users from modifying PayPal code?

Tags: html, forms

I have a "Pay Now" button from Paypal on my website. However, anyone can easily modify the amount they have to pay.

Here's the code that PayPal generated:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="**1000.00**">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Anyone can change the "1000.00" to "100.00". Is there a way to prevent this or a better way to accept payments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [Securing Your Website Payments Standard Buttons](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments) it outlines some of things you can do to protect yourself from this. One of the things is to create buttons with their online tool, and save them. When a purchase is made, they compare it with the saved button and check to make sure they are the same.